# Conditional require a module

Tags: jquery, requirejs

Im starting now with RequireJS and im trying to require modules conditionaly.

Basically what i want to do is:

- Require jQuery.
- Check if have a element with X data tag. `$('[data-myplugin]').length > 0`
- If true, require the *myplugin* plugin
- After loaded, star *myplugin* `$('[data-myplugin]').myplugin()`

**There is a way to do this with RequireJS?**

**Is this a good approach?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write your `main.js` like bellow:

```
var reqs = ["jquery"];

/* you must make sure that the '$'(jquery already loaded) can be used.
 * or you should use pure javaScript code to do the test */
if($('[data-myplugin]').length > 0) {
    reqs.push("myplugin");
}

require( reqs,

function() {
    if($('[data-myplugin]').length > 0) {
        $('[data-myplugin]').myplugin();
    }
});
```